# Unable to refresh access token : response is "unauthorized_client"

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I am getting an error when I try to refresh access token:

> 400 Bad Request
>
> {error : "unauthorized_client"}

From the Google token URI:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

I read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792326/how-do-i-refresh-my-google-oauth2-access-token-using-my-refresh-token) and the official Google documentation (which describes how a `POST` request should look) and I don't see any difference.

I captured my `POST` request (secrets removed):

```
POST /SHOWMERAWPOST HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Google-HTTP-Java-Client/1.10.3-beta (gzip)
Pragma: no-cache
Host: requestb.in
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 175
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2

grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=******&client_id=*******.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=******
```

Java code which sends the request:

```
RefreshTokenRequest req = new RefreshTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new GenericUrl(
                    getSecrets().getDetails().getTokenUri()), REFRESH_TOKEN);

           req.set("client_id", getSecrets().getDetails().getClientId());
           req.set("client_secret", getSecrets().getDetails().getClientSecret());

           TokenResponse response = req.execute();
```

*Is there anything wrong?*

Comment: did u find the answer, getting the same error
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878605/authorize-google-calendar-api-works-on-personal-account-but-not-on-google-domain)

Comment: I do not need to impersonate user, i am sending only client and secret id with refresh token. That`s different situation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I created access and refresh token in OAuth2 playground and then i copied them to my app.
It`s not allowed to have different clients for autorization and for token refresh.

Comment: It`s not allowed to have different clients for autorization and for token refresh >> Martin can you explain it a bit more.. I am facing similar issue..

thank you.

Comment: Hi Martin can you please let me know what you did to solve this error. i am facing same problem.

Comment: Please define what a client is...
IP Address, User Agent, how does it know?

Comment: this problem happens when u are using the refresh token is generated by [clientid,screretid] which is different from [clientid,screredid] is used for authorizing process.

Answer (score 45):

**PROBLEM EXPLANATION**

With the hint @MartinV gave I was finally able to fix it! Because his answer doesn't explain very well how to solve it, I'm going to post it here.

The problem is because we all have generated the Refresh Token using [Google's OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), but when you click 'Authorize APIs' in the first step, it takes you to the concent screen using the Playground app. After that, all the tokens that you create can be used only by the Playground app, but of course you don't know either the Client ID or the Client Secret for that app.

**SOLUTION**

The solution is to make Playground to use your own Client ID and Secret. To do so, click on the Settings button:

[image: Playground settings]

And enter your Client ID and Secret.  But, before you do that, as it says there, you need to go to the [Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), find your *OAuth 2.0 client IDs* client, edit it and add *https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground* under *Authorized redirect URIs*. After you added that and saved the changes, go back to the playground and try to Authorize APIs.  In my case it took like 15 minutes before the changes in the *Authorized redirect URIs* took effect.

Once you're done, don't forget to remove the Playground URI from the Developer Console!

**EXTRA**

Once I have done that, in Python I did this and it worked:

```
access_token = None 
client_id = 'xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
refresh_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
token_expiry = None
token_uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
user_agent = 'YourAgent/1.0'

credentials = client.GoogleCredentials(access_token, client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, token_expiry, token_uri, user_agent)

http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
credentials.refresh(http)

service = build('drive', 'v3', http=http)
req = service.files().list()
resp = req.execute(http=http)
```

Comment: I have followed all your steps but after completion of whole process refresh_token is blank while I got access token in oauthplayground.

Comment: Not sure I understand. In Playground, you need to click _Exchange authorization code for tokens_ to get the Refresh Token.

Comment: i tried to test on localhost, and set my redirect uri to playground but i got: "redirect_uri_mismatch" in my localhost server

Comment: Not sure if it's using just the redirect parameter or the _referrer_. I don't remember. In any case, did you way a few minutes after adding the playground URL under in the Dev's console?

Comment: This answer should have been the correct thorough answer - you literally saved me! haha

Comment: Thank you!  Google needs to clean up their act and put this info in their docs.

Comment: I am sure your answer solved the problem extremely difficult,I went to find it a long time.I love you @Diego Jancic

Comment: OMG! THANK YOU!!!!....after reviewing tons of StackOverflow postings on the topic, reviewing multiple tutorials on the general topic and pulling out my hair for a week+ trying to figure out why my programmatic request to refresh tokens failed...THIS appears to have solved the problem.   I agree with @user1701153 that Google needs better documentation...it's really horrific! Argh!

Comment: I agree with @Raven this should have been the CORRECT answer!

Comment: Oh Jesus! I was fighting with this problem for several days, until I found this post.
Thank you man, this should be accepted answer!!! 
@google please update your docs. This is not normal!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the REST API to get an `access_token` and then use it to interact with the REST API (e.g. add a video to a private playlist) after creating the `refresh_token` as described [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556775/3774227).

```
import requests
import json

# according to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556775/3774227
client_id = '<client_id>'
client_secret = '<client_secret>'
refresh_token = '<refresh_token>'

playlist_id = '<playlist>'
video_id = 'M7FIvfx5J10'


def get_access_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):

    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token'

    data = {
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'refresh_token': refresh_token,
        'grant_type': 'refresh_token'
    }

    response = requests.post(
        url=url,
        data=data,
    )

    return response.json().get('access_token')


def add_video_to_playlist(playlist_id, video_id, access_token):

    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems'

    params = {
        'part': 'snippet',
    }

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
    }

    data = {
        'snippet': {
            'playlistId': playlist_id,
            'resourceId': {
                'kind': 'youtube#video',
                'videoId': video_id
            },
        }
    }

    requests.post(
        url=url,
        params=params,
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(data)
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    access_token = get_access_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token)
    add_video_to_playlist(playlist_id, video_id, access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution was to use the same client when authorizing in the application and when updating the token on the server.

[Can't refresh access token for Google Calendar API on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52928598/cant-refresh-access-token-for-google-calendar-api-on-server-side/52945725)