# Google oAuth2 unauthorized_client by refresh_token

Tags: perl, google-plus, google-oauth

i'm trying to use an refresh token from the oAuth2 web redirect auth in my console perl script. The client id is the same and correct client id i used in my javascript an i checked it 5 times that it ist the same as i have in my google API's Console.

The client secret is checked two and it is correct.

The refresh token was created with `approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline`

Here is my perl sample code i use:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
my $CLIENT_ID     = 'XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
my $CLIENT_SECRET = 'YYYYYYYYYYY';
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TESTING
my $refresh_token = '1/is_5_minutes_old';
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

my $string = '';
$string .= 'grant_type=refresh_token';
$string .= '&client_id=' . $CLIENT_ID;
$string .= '&client_secret=' . $CLIENT_SECRET;
$string .= '&refresh_token=' . $refresh_token;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $req =
  HTTP::Request->new( POST => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' );
$req->content_type('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$req->content($string);
print $string . "\n";
my $res = $ua->request($req);
print $res->as_string;
```

The response of it:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 10:50:26 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: GSE
Content-Type: application/json
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Client-Date: Mon, 02 Sep 2013 10:50:26 GMT
Client-Peer: 74.125.136.84:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=accounts.google.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: RC4-SHA
Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

{
  "error" : "unauthorized_client"
}
```

i hope you have an idea to help.

greatings

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Invalid client usually means that the client ID and client secret don't match, or there is a typo in one of them (though you mention you've double checked this!). Nothing in your code looks wrong.

When you retrieve the refresh token, could you try putting the access token that comes along with it into the tokeinfo endpoint and making sure the values for client ID there match the ones you've configured with: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=

It might be worth dumping out the request to make sure there isn't a mistake in that (e.g. too short a content-length header or similar).

Comment: If using Playground to generate the code you'll want to set your own client and secret there to avoid this error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41556775/6654475

Answer (score 2):

Dumping the request is key. To help , here is one I baked earlier..

```
==POST== 
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
refresh_token=1/_PEzU2m71wertwertwerJUtrtrytrytryf3trytryoCo
&client_id=612222222225
&client_secret=Q7334534543534yKLu
&grant_type=refresh_token
```

Are you using the short form of the client id, ie. just the number?