# How many times can I use a refresh token obtained from google api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have developed a rails application that allows a user to login using their google account and then the application fetches the emails and parses them for information.

All this works fine, but I am facing issues with access token become invalid, hence I have been looking into refreshing the token. I found some code at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491560/718087

With this code I have been able to get a new access token that works. But I have a few questions:

1. How many times can I use the same refresh token I got the first time? or do I need update my refresh token as well, each time I get a new access token? note: application is setup with offline access.
2. Do I need to refresh the token before it expires or it will still return to me a valid token after the old access token has expired? This will allow me to decide an approach as to when I should refresh the tokens - a: right before fetching the emails, b: automatically before the token expires via delayed jobs or something (this would add quite a overhead though)

I have gone through the api docs but could not find answer to my these specific questions. Please excuse my overly detailed queries.

Thanks,
Aditya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refresh tokens never expire, unless revoked by the user.  You should store it safely and permanently.  You should definitely *not* go back and get new refresh tokens over and over, because only a certain number can be understanding per user/app combination, and eventually the older ones will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question: "Do I need to refresh the token before it expires or it will still return to me a valid token after the old access token has expired?"

I have a rails app, and I check for expiration & refresh token existence:

```
if client.authorization.expired? && client.authorization.refresh_token
 #then I refresh here...
```

So the answer is, Yes you can (and probably should) wait until your access token expires, and then refresh it.